# I2C on RPi4 with 24LC512

Tags: i2c, raspberry-pi4, eeprom

```sh
$ i2cdetect -r -y 1
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: 50 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

$ i2cset -y 1 0x50 0xff 0x21

$ i2cget 1 0x50 0xff
WARNING! This program can confuse your I2C bus, cause data loss and worse!
I will read from device file /dev/i2c-1, chip address 0x50, data address

0xff, using read byte data.
Continue? [Y/n] Y

0x20
```

It’s  detected fine, but set, get are not working in 24lc512.

Comment: Enable `at24` eeprom driver, write a section in DTS and use simply `dd if=/sys/...path to eeprom file...`.

Comment: If your goal is to train your skills on writing device drivers in user space, look into source code of that kernel driver.

Comment: sorry sir i am not understand , how to enable at 24...?